# mddyyy convert to mmddyyyy in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a file which contains dates like 5062014(not properly formatted) along with dates like 05062014(properly formatted) in excel.How to change those dates which are not properly formatted.Can we apply any formula in excel for that?

Comment: `=TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy")`

Comment: Are these actual date values (i.e. date value of 05-Jun-2014 is 41,795 while 06-May-2014 is 41,765) or just a number (i.e actual value of 5062014 is 5,062,014 and 05062014 is a text)?.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can convert the dates with this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e